# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL using Next-auth only in Production

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

The app fails on trying to sign in using next-auth in my Next.js app in production mode when using the following command in the terminal on my local machine:

`yarn build && yarn start`

The error message observed in the terminal is as follows:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:553:9)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:629:5)
    at Object.redirect (/Users/name/Documents/GitHub/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/default-callbacks.js:16:65)
    at createCallbackUrl (/Users/name/Documents/GitHub/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/callback-url.js:20:35)
    at init (/Users/name/Documents/GitHub/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/init.js:132:48)
    at AuthHandlerInternal (/Users/name/Documents/GitHub/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:98:28)
    at AuthHandler (/Users/name/Documents/GitHub/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:335:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async NextAuthHandler (/Users/name/Documents/GitHub/app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:38:20) {
  input: 'undefined/home',
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
}
```

If I run in development mode with the following command in the terminal, the issue does not occur:

`yarn dev`

This is my [...nextauth].ts file:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";

import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      // @ts-ignore
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      // @ts-ignore
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      // @ts-ignore
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      // @ts-ignore
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
        port: Number(process.env.SMTP_PORT),
        auth: {
          user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
          pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
        },
      },
      from: process.env.SMTP_FROM,
    }),
  ],

  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,

  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session?.user) {
        // @ts-ignore
        session.user.id = token.uid;
      }
      return session;
    },
    jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.uid = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",

    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days

    // updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
  },

  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

I tried figuring out what is different in production regarding the error message `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL` but could not figure it out. I haven't changed any environmental variables, and I have set the following variables in .env.local:

```
NEXTAUTH_SECRET="SomeLongString"
```

```
NEXTAUTH_URL="http://localhost:3000"
```

Adding package.json on request:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.4",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.13",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.5",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.7.1",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.8",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "eslint": "8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.4",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.7",
    "graphql-request": "^5.0.0",
    "next": "13.0.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.18.6",
    "next-seo": "^5.14.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.8.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.40.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "swr": "^1.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "4.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier-plugin-prisma": "^4.4.0",
    "prisma": "^4.7.1"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess, the `url` you build for production is `localhost`, you need to change it to live url.

Comment: As it says `input: 'undefined/home'`, it looks like you've got a variable for your base URL that isn't being initialized properly.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. It seems that it would read my env in production.

I'm using this function to define whether I'm in development or production

Comment: const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
  const basePath = dev ? "http://localhost:3000" : process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL;

Comment: I guess that `NEXTAUTH_URL` is `undefined`

Comment: Can you include `package.json` to your question?

Comment: @ivanatias I've added it to the original description now.

Comment: can you show us part where you added code `process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL` and `const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"; const basePath = dev ? "localhost:3000" : process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL;` or this part of code `input: 'undefined/home'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's because you're using the development link `NEXTAUTH_URL="http://localhost:3000"` in production. Instead, use the live link `NEXTAUTH_URL="yourwebsite.com"` in production.

Also, instead of doing an if-statement to check whether you're in development or in production, have 2 `.env` files - one locally with the localhost url, and the one on live with the live url. This can help you better diagnose issues.

More so, check to confirm that your env variables are actually accessible in your app.

Answer (score 5):

NEXTAUTH_URL is undefined. You need to define [NEXTAUTH_URL](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options) in your [.env file](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables).

[NextJs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order) has built in ways to allow you to use different environment variables whether you are testing, developing or in production. Though usually in production you'd just have a single .env as you don't want to commit your secrets to git.

Comment: NEXTAUTH_URL is defined in my .env.local file. I'm using the following function to determine whether the app is running in development or production mode.

Comment: const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"; const basePath = dev ? "localhost:3000" : process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL;

Comment: What's basePath used for? Have you tried deleting the .next build folder? Console.log the environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

NextJS has two policies about looking for environment files, what you have to know though is that:

- For localhost and whatever scenario where NODE_ENV is not production, nextjs will be looking for the `.env.local` file.
- **For production scenarios (where NODE_ENV is production), it will look for `.env.production`.**

Moreover, these rules also applies:

- All the variables defined in the env file (either .env.local, either .env.production) are available server-side.
- [Variables starting with `NEXT_PUBLIC` are available client side.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

Also, you need to consider that:

- Environment variables are evaluated at **BUILD TIME**, so you must ensure that the correct `.env.[local|production]` file exists and has the relevant data at **BUILD TIME**. [Taking from the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables):

> Note: In order to keep server-only secrets safe, environment variables are evaluated at build time, so only environment variables actually used will be included. This means that process.env is not a standard JavaScript object, so you’re not able to use object destructuring. Environment variables must be referenced as e.g. process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY, not const { PUBLISHABLE_KEY } = process.env.

As a final side note, I suggest you to also consider [this chapter](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) where it basically mentions that those .env files should be under version control, other than the `env*.local` ones in case you have multiple .env.local files. Another important side note is that the command you are running to start the next server must be `next start` and not `next dev`, where the environment in case of `next dev` is specifically `development`.

**Summarized, either of the above are your problem, although I think that the problem is that you probably are missing the .env.production at build time.**

Answer (score 2):

You are using development NEXTAUTH_URL for release. You need to define NEXTAUTH_URL in your .env file with your production link.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error **"TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL"**.

All the responses above are valid, however in my case I was getting this error when building the app (npm run build) as part of a Dockerfile.

My issue was that while I was executing the 'docker build' from the command line I was forgetting to pass an argument that contain the NEXTAUTH_URL. Then obviously the Invalid URL on the error message.

Infant mistake on my side but it might happen to others.